# Torque on rod caused by torque on ring

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, torque

Consider the following arrangement where a rod is hung by two strings from a ceiling:

[image]

A charged ring rotates about its center with an angular velocity $\omega$. There is a uniform magnetic field directed upwards.

Since a current is produced on the ring due to rotation, it experiences a torque of magnitude $\frac{Q\omega}{2} r^2B$ where $Q$ is the charge on the ring and $r$ the radius.

I dont undersand how this torque affects the rotational equilibrium of the rod itself.

Comment: Where is the rod?

Comment: Im so sorry. The rod is hung by two strings from a ceiling(as shown)